# I can't force a geography with ConsentDebugSettings to test the UMP SDK

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement the UMP SDK following the guide provided by google:

[UMP SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy)

I am using `ConsentDebugSettings` to pretend that I am in the European Union but I am not able to show the dialog to give consent. I already tried with emulator and with physical device, I also replaced "TEST-DEVICE-HASHED-ID" with the id of my physical device and I can't get it to work.
The only solution I have found is to download a VPN app to change the region of my device and this works but I don't know if I should trust that method.

This is my code:

```
private ConsentInformation consentInformation;
private ConsentForm consentForm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ConsentDebugSettings debugSettings = new ConsentDebugSettings.Builder(this)
            .setDebugGeography(ConsentDebugSettings.DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA)
            .addTestDeviceHashedId("TEST-DEVICE-HASHED-ID")
            .build();


    // Set tag for under age of consent. false means users are not under
    // age.
    ConsentRequestParameters params = new ConsentRequestParameters
            .Builder()
            .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)
            .setConsentDebugSettings(debugSettings)
            .build();

    consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this);
    consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
            this,
            params,
            new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentInfoUpdateSuccess() {
                    // The consent information state was updated.
                    // You are now ready to check if a form is available.
                    if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable()) {
                        loadForm();
                    }
                }
            },
            new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentInfoUpdateFailure(FormError formError) {
                    // Handle the error.
                }
            });
}

public void loadForm() {
    // Loads a consent form. Must be called on the main thread.
    UserMessagingPlatform.loadConsentForm(
            this,
            new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadSuccessListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentFormLoadSuccess(ConsentForm consentForm) {
                    MainActivity.this.consentForm = consentForm;
                    if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                        consentForm.show(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                new ConsentForm.OnConsentFormDismissedListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onConsentFormDismissed(@Nullable FormError formError) {
                                        if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.OBTAINED) {
                                            // App can start requesting ads.
                                        }

                                        // Handle dismissal by reloading form.
                                        loadForm();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            },
            new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentFormLoadFailure(FormError formError) {
                    // Handle Error.
                }
            }
    );
}
```

In addition to this, I have some other questions.

If there is no consent from the user, I can configure the ads so that they are not personalized? How do I do that? I have seen [the example of google](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/main/java/admob/BannerExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/bannerexample) and they simply don't load the ads if there is no consent, then a user can choose to be premium without paying (by not giving consent). How have you handled this situation?